# Calculate availability with dates

Tags: r

I have a tibble and want to compute monthly availability (A), defined as

A = uptime / (uptime + downtime),

where (monthly) downtime is `end` - `start`, by month and uptime is total time (1 month) - downtime. What is the way to compute monthly availability for the year 2019?

This is the sample data

```r
structure(list(start = structure(c(1550048400, 1558008000, 1558703040, 
1561032000, 1560945660, 1563451200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), end = structure(c(1550143989, 1558008000, 1558956840, 
1561032000, 1560945660, 1563451200), tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please write better the formulas you need? Is downtime by month so difference in months? Is uptime total time (what is?) - downtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have inconsistent `"tzone"` attributes, one is `"UTC"` and the other is `"GMT"`. It's minor (and slightly noisy), so I'll preempt the noise (though no change in the results):

```r
attr(dat$end, "tzone") <- "UTC"
```

A helper function:

```r
fun <- function(mon1, mon2, x = dat) {
  # if either start/end is between mon1/mon2, include it ...
  tmp <- x[with(x, (start >= mon1 & start < mon2) | (end >= mon1 & end < mon2)),] |>
    # ... but if start-to-end straddles a month begin/end, then truncate it
    transform(
      start = pmax(start, mon1),
      end = pmin(end, mon2)
    )
  data.frame(start = mon1, end = mon2) |>
    transform(downtime = c(sum(with(tmp, as.numeric(end - start, units = "hours"))), 0)[1]) |>
    transform(uptime = as.numeric(mon2 - mon1, units = "hours") - downtime) |>
    transform(A = uptime / ( uptime + downtime))
}
```

And the work in base R:

```r
months <- seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), by="1 month", length.out=12)
months
#  [1] "2019-01-01 UTC" "2019-02-01 UTC" "2019-03-01 UTC" "2019-04-01 UTC" "2019-05-01 UTC" "2019-06-01 UTC" "2019-07-01 UTC"
#  [8] "2019-08-01 UTC" "2019-09-01 UTC" "2019-10-01 UTC" "2019-11-01 UTC" "2019-12-01 UTC"
do.call(rbind, Map(fun, months[-12], months[-1]))
#         start        end downtime   uptime         A
# 1  2019-01-01 2019-02-01   0.0000 744.0000 1.0000000
# 2  2019-02-01 2019-03-01  26.5525 645.4475 0.9604874
# 3  2019-03-01 2019-04-01   0.0000 744.0000 1.0000000
# 4  2019-04-01 2019-05-01   0.0000 720.0000 1.0000000
# 5  2019-05-01 2019-06-01  70.5000 673.5000 0.9052419
# 6  2019-06-01 2019-07-01   0.0000 720.0000 1.0000000
# 7  2019-07-01 2019-08-01   0.0000 744.0000 1.0000000
# 8  2019-08-01 2019-09-01   0.0000 744.0000 1.0000000
# 9  2019-09-01 2019-10-01   0.0000 720.0000 1.0000000
# 10 2019-10-01 2019-11-01   0.0000 744.0000 1.0000000
# 11 2019-11-01 2019-12-01   0.0000 720.0000 1.0000000
```

Comment: This is great! I think is working for my use case, but I might need to adjust it for special cases. I'm trying to rewrite it so I can iterate through different dataframes. Changing `x` to be an unvalued argument and the `Map` line doesn't work. How would you adjust your function to do so?

Comment: Yeah, good point. First, I edited it to replace a typo (changed `dat` to `x` internally, my bad). From there, try `Map(function(m1, m2) fun(m1, m2, x=dat), months[-12], months[12])` for the single-case, and `lapply(list_of_frames, function(Z) Map(function(m1, m2) fun(m1, m2, x=Z), months[-12], months[12]))` for the next step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to calculate the value of 'A' for each month, then the process would be:

- sum up all the down time in each month
- subtract that from the total time in the month to get the uptime
- divide the uptime by the total time in the month

This is possible using the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

   data <- data %>% 
      mutate(downtime = end-start,
             month = format(end, "%Y-%m %b"),
             month_time = ceiling_date(end, 
                                       unit = "months") - floor_date(end, 
                                                                     unit = "months")) %>% 
      group_by(month) %>% 
      summarise(downtime = sum(downtime),
                month_time = month_time[1]) %>% 
      mutate(uptime = month_time - downtime,
             A = as.numeric(uptime) / as.numeric(uptime + downtime))
```

[image]

Comment: r2evans answer deals with events crossing month boundaries - whereas the above does not (yet)

Comment: Yes, crossing month boundaries are important for this case. Sorry for not pointing it out.